# React-Select Scrollbar Styling

Tags: reactjs, frontend, scrollbar, styling, react-select

I am trying to change the style of scrollbar from react-select and customise it. Anyone have any idea how?

This is the code in css that I want to style it to

```
  /* Scroll Bar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 0px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try overriding `react-select` css:

```
  /* Scroll Bar */
select__menu-list::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
  height: 0px;
}
select__menu-list::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}
select__menu-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}
select__menu-list::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

In react-select v4+, we use like [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4211#issuecomment-691541202)

```
const styles = {
  menuList: (base) => ({
    ...base,

    "::-webkit-scrollbar": {
      width: "4px",
      height: "0px",
    },
    "::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
      background: "#f1f1f1"
    },
    "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
      background: "#888"
    },
    "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover": {
      background: "#555"
    }
  });
}
return <Select styles={styles} ... />
```

Comment: Highly recommened using this solution instead of the accepted one

Comment: This should be the accepted one