# react select with border radius scroll is overflowing

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-select

I made a react-select with border radius and max height on my menu. The problem is that the scrollbar background is overflowing and hiding the menu border[image: scroll overflow]

here is my css:

```
export const customStyles = {
  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: "#969696",
    backgroundColor: "white !important",
    boxShadow: "none",
    borderColor: "#969696",
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
    "&:hover": {
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  }),
  menu: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    width: "100%",
    borderRadius: "0px 0px 17.02px 17.02px",
    marginBottom: 0,
    boxShadow: "none",
    marginTop: 0,
    border: "1px solid #969696",
    maxHeight: "33vh",
    borderTop: 0,
  }),
  menuList: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    boxShadow: "none",
    borderRadius: "0px 0px 17.02px 17.02px",
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
  }),
  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    boxShadow: "none",
    borderRadius: state.menuIsOpen ? "17.02px 17.02px 0px 0px" : "17.02px",
    borderColor: state.menuIsOpen ? "#969696" : "#5776FF",
    borderBottom: state.menuIsOpen ? 0 : "",
    "&:hover": {
      borderColor: "#969696",
    },
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      color: "#979797",
  }),
  container: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    width: "100%",
  }),
  valueContainer: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
  }),
  indicatorSeparator: () => ({
    display: "none",
  }),
};
```

I tried to add border radius to the scrollbar but it makes him disappear...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide overflow hidden to the `menu`

```js
menu: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    width: "100%",
    borderRadius: "0px 0px 17.02px 17.02px",
    marginBottom: 0,
    boxShadow: "none",
    marginTop: 0,
    border: "1px solid #969696",
    maxHeight: "10vh",
    borderTop: 0,
    overflow : 'hidden' //<---- like this
  }),
```

Alternatively, you can refer some solutions [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/780) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413762/react-select-scrollbar-styling)