# Mobile scrollbar for react-select defaults to browser style?

Tags: react-select

I have a react-select component with a custom scrollbar that works in desktop browsers as expected, but on mobile the scrollbar defaults to browser values.

Referencing [a similar github issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4211) and [a similar stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413762/react-select-scrollbar-styling) have not helped resolve this issue.

```
const styles = {
  menu: provided => ({
    ...provided,
    width: '100%',
    height: '240px',
    boxShadow: '0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)',
    overflowY: 'scroll',
    '::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb': {
      background: royal, // imported color string
      height: '50px',
    },
    '::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover': {
      background: royal,
      height: '50px',
    },
    '::-webkit-scrollbar-track': {
      background: softGrey,
    },
    '::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      width: '4px',
      background: softGrey,
    },
  }),
  menuList: () => ({
    '::-webkit-scrollbar': {
      width: '4px',
    },
  }),
}
```

```
<Select
  placeholder={placeholder}
  styles={styles}
  onMenuOpen={onOpenHandler}
  onMenuClose={onCloseHandler}
  onChange={onChangeHandler}
  onInputChange={() => {}}
  controlShouldRenderValue
  label={label}
  value={value}
  defaultValue={defaultValue}
  options={options}
/>
```

The github references using menuList, but I found that using menu and menuList got me the desired style. I tried every variant of:

- using !important
- moving only to menuList
- having in both menu and menuList
- using react-select v2 (2.4.1) and v3 (3.2.0)

[image: Mobile browser]

[image: What it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently iOS 14 webkit doesn't support custom scrollbars anymore.

https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4439#issuecomment-776297882

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670065?answerId=654532022#654532022